# What do these characters in Swift mean <>. If I wrapped a keyword In them, what would that mean exactly

Tags: swift, swiftui

For example if I have:

```
var hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>! = nil
```

What does it example mean when I put content inside the greater than and less than signs?

Comment: It's a generic definition

Comment: Im sorry im new to swift.

Comment: [Swift Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)

Comment: How would this affect later implementation of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a generic definition. Generics are useful when you’re writing code that could be applied to many different types. 
For example, that means that UIHostingController could be initialised with any view.

```
 hostingController = UIHostingController.init(rootView: ContentView())

 struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
       Text("some text")
   }
 }
```

Hope this is helpful!